# How to return absolute values using ArcMap field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator

I have a field of number ranging from -50 to 50. Is there a way using the ArcMap field calculator to populate a field with all of these standardised (positive numbers) so I have a range of 0 to 50 (where something that was previously -1 is now 1).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When opening Field Calculator, if using the VB Script parser (the default) you can use the Abs() function around your field name. Similarly, if using Python, use abs() around your field name.

Comment: Glad to help. I edited my response to include both VB Script and Python.